# Interact with FX Connect

Tags: programming, fx, algorithmic-trading

I have little to no programming background so please bear with me. I work for a firm that executes our FX trades via FX Connect. I would like to program some logic into FX Connect so that trades that meet a certain criteria will  automatically send trades.

Comment: You cannot "program logic into FX Connect". But the way I imagine if works is there is a program at your firm that uses an API (application programming interface) to send an order to FX Connect. That same program can be modified to, for example, also send the order to another system or do something else with it in addition to sending it to FX Connect. But it would seem to require in-depth programming knowledge and would have to involve the people responsible for that program.

Answer (score 1):

ForEx Connect C++ API. You can find out more about it [here.](http://fxcodebase.com/wiki/index.php/Start_Using_ForexConnect_API_(C%2B%2B_Win32/Win64)) That said, you will definitely need some programming in your toolkit in order to achieve what you're setting out to do. Good luck.